# Is it possible to view / edit WCF configuration inside <system.Servicemodel> in web.config ASP .Net web application by user interface in IIS Manager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I need to edit WCF configuration inside  in web.config ASP .Net web application for some bug fixing. But due to the company policy I cannot edit the configuration directly in the web.config file. I need to find a way an alternative way to edit / view the configuration, and what I think is if I can edit or view the configuration by user interface in IIS manager. But I haven't find the WCF configuration in IIS manager. Is it possible to view / edit WCF configuration inside  in web.config ASP .Net web application by user interface in IIS Manager?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Right click the service reference and see what you can do from there. Also look into [svcutility tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe). Also, tell your company to take a hike because they're making your job harder for no reason;)

Comment: @CodingYoshi The company where I work for should take a hike, that is exactly what I think :). Well I propose to edit the configuration directly in the production server with backup it first, but the change management team who responsible for production deployment reject that method. They were insist to use the 'replace' method not 'write' in the production server. However, my supervisor reject my request to take the existing web.config from production server because security reason. He said there are sensitive information written in the config. Thank you for the suggestion, though :).

Comment: As far as I know, it may not work. Once the service is managed, it runs the service using the configuration defined in the system.servicemodel section. If we modify these services in a runtime environment, I think we must restart the service to apply the configuration of these changes.

Comment: @abrahamqian If you make any changes to the config, it will trigger IIS to reload the application. Once there are zero connections left, it will reload the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, how to VIEW the web.config, if your IIS permissions will allow so:

1. Open IIS Manager and your Site
2. On the bottom, there's Management/Confuguration Editor
3. There are some predefined sections to view in upper "Section" selector, but system.serviceModel is missing.
4. Click "Search configuration" on the right panel.
5. Navigate to your web.config file

Now you can see the entire secret hidden there.

This will only provide read-only access if your IIS account will allow that. I don't know how to write to it.